# Array object only displaying final data for each index in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm creating an array of objects in Javascript. The object data is being generated on the fly in a for loop.

When you run this code you'll see that the final array generated in the console log is all the same data for each index.

I'm new to Javascript, but I do have experience with arrays in C++, Python, VBA, etc.

I realize there are other types of loops for arrays like ForEach, and Mapping, but
this seems like it should be very straightforward, but I have no idea what I'm missing.

```js
const test_data = {
  value: 0,
  value2: 0
};

let number = 10;

let test_array = [];
let temp = test_data;

for (let i = 0; i < number; i++) {

  //i realize using a temp object is a little redundant
  //being that i could just say test_array[i].value = ***
  //i get the same results either way.
  temp.value = 500 * (i + 1);
  temp.value2 = temp.value * 100;

  test_array.push(test_data);
  test_array[i] = temp;

  console.log(temp);
  console.log(test_array[i]);
  console.log(test_array);

}

console.log(test_array);
```

Comment: You have only one temp object. The array is containing multiple references to the same temp object. You change the values of that one temp object. The array containing multiple references will show the latest/last value in that temp object. You need to create clone your temp object or create new object instances.

Comment: You can replace with spread operator `test_array[i] = {...temp};` to store the value.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? What's the final output you wish to achieve? It's all the same because 1) you're setting static values for your objects, so those values won't change to some different value. 2) you push the test_data object into the array, but it gets immediately overwritten by your test_array[i] logic, as i will always correspond to the current push of the array as i is equal to your current iteration and the exact same index of the array you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

Objects are passed by reference in JS, so in your code on each iteration you are modifying the same object and adding a link to it in your array.

You will have to either create copies of the `temp` object whenever you add it to the array or, since you modify all properties, create a new object and set it before adding it.

```js
let number = 10;
let test_array = [];

for (let i = 0; i < number; i++) {
  const temp = {};
  temp.value = 500 * (i + 1);
  temp.value2 = temp.value * 100;

  test_array.push(temp);
}

console.log(test_array);
```

---

Or if you wan to create copies from the original (*because there are other data you want to keep*)

```js
const test_data = {
  value: 0,
  value2: 0,
  common_data: 'some common value'
};

let number = 10;

let test_array = [];

for (let i = 0; i < number; i++) {
  // create shallow copy
  const temp = {...test_data};
  
  temp.value = 500 * (i + 1);
  temp.value2 = temp.value * 100;

  test_array.push(temp);
}

console.log(test_array);
```

---

Finally, if you want to create copies and the `test_data` holds other objects in it, you might want to do a [deep copy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Deep_copy) instead

Answer (score 0):

As @Stephen Quan mentioned in his comment you have multiple reference and reference to the same object.

To solve this issue you can use the spread operator to create the new copy of the object.

```
  for (let i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    let temp = test_data;

    temp.value = 500 * (i + 1);
    temp.value2 = temp.value * 100;
    test_array[i] = {...temp};
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is what you are looking for

```js
const test_data = {
    value: 0,
    value2: 0
};

const start = 1;
const end = 10;
const number = [...Array(end - start + 1).keys()].map(x => x + start);

const test_array = number.map((_, index) => {
    let value = 500 * (index + 1);
    let value2 = value * 100;
    return {value, value2};
});

console.log(test_array);
```

Output:

```bash
[
    {
        "value": 500,
        "value2": 50000
    },
    {
        "value": 1000,
        "value2": 100000
    },
    {
        "value": 1500,
        "value2": 150000
    },
    {
        "value": 2000,
        "value2": 200000
    },
    {
        "value": 2500,
        "value2": 250000
    },
    {
        "value": 3000,
        "value2": 300000
    },
    {
        "value": 3500,
        "value2": 350000
    },
    {
        "value": 4000,
        "value2": 400000
    },
    {
        "value": 4500,
        "value2": 450000
    },
    {
        "value": 5000,
        "value2": 500000
    }
]
```